# User meta and author meta

Tags: functions

Here's what I have so far..

```
class emailer {
function notifyHeart($post_ID)  {

    $interests = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'interests', TRUE );
    $to = the_author_meta( 'user_email', get_current_user_id() );

    if(has_tag($interests[0])) {
        $email = $to;
        mail($email, "An article about Heart", 
          'A new post has been published about heart.');
        return $post_ID;
    }
}
}

add_action('publish_post', array('emailer', 'notifyHeart'));
```

What I need to do now, before actually sending the email, I need something that checks if the user has an $interest and if so, send them an email. Any help with this?

Comment: removing `[0]` from `$interests[0]` will remove the php error. Though i don't really understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Well the [0] I need so that the correct "interest" in the area can be matched to a tag from a post.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, after a post has been published, find out its tags, if the tags match a user's "interests" which I have already gathered in the database, then email that user.

Comment: For future reference, `[0]` will actually throw an error. The `TRUE` in `get_user_meta` will return only one of the tags in the database. That will mean that `$interests` there is a string & not array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class emailer {
  static function notifyHeart($post_ID)  {
    $interests = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'interests');
    $to = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', get_current_user_id() );
    $post = get_post($post_ID);

    foreach($interests as $interest) {
      if(has_tag($interest, $post)) {
        $email = $to;
        mail($email, "An article about Heart", 'A new post has been published about heart.');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action('publish_post', array('emailer', 'notifyHeart'));
```

Here's a reworked example. It retrieves all the tags you have in database as meta, checks each of them & if it matches the one in that post's id, it will send the mail & break out of the loop.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm receiving the following error now.. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.. it occurs after publishing a post.

Comment: that error shouldn't be related to mail function. maybe due to something else. Have you recieved the email?

Comment: Thank you, it's working now, however, it's only sending email to one user with a match, the other user on the site, that selected a different interest ins't receiving the email.

Comment: that's cuz you only checked for the current(logged in) user. To check for all users , you can use [`get_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) & then loop through all the users to send them the email